# ScriptReferenceName Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am making a Guess the Number game in Visual Studios 2013 with the language JavaScript. I was just wondeing how to use this code`<asp:ScriptReferenceName="guess-number.js"Assembly="System.Web"Path="~/Games/guess-number/guess-number.js" />` in my page. I am using ASP.

The only problem is that it gives me an error saying:

> Element 'ScriptReferenceName' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the website, or the web.config file is missing.

Is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an element which goes by the name `ScriptReference` and not `ScriptReferenceName` . Name is a property of this element, which was included without a space which led to this specific error.

```
<Sripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="guess-something.js" />
</Scripts>
```

And this should be part of the `<asp:ScriptManager` parent tag

Comment: Which page do I put it on?

Comment: The `aspx` page where you want to include this script.